# Monitor performance impact of Anti-virus in server

Tags: sql-server, performance, production-environment, antivirus

We have anti virus software installed in our production database servers (SQL Server 2014 on Windows 2012 R2). We have been encountering I/O issues and I would like to definitely rule out the antivirus.

Our IT teams have assured me that the antivirus excludes the database data and log drives. I would like to validate that this is the case.

The test I have done so far, is using Process Monitor and monitor file system access to the database data and log drives. I performed the following in our Staging environment which is set up closely to our production environment. I did not find anything (other of course than SQL Server).

Is this a good test? I am just not sure it is a valid method since antivirus I believe hook into the file system.

Are there anything else I could do?

The AV software that we use is Trend Micro.

Thanks

Comment: This question seems more suited to http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/.  It would also help to know information about the `I/O issues`.  What are they?  How do you know it's an issue?  Where are your servers running?  For instance, some cloud hosting throttles CPU and I/O.  Have you used Performance Monitor to watch I/O times.  Is the queue length maxed out?  What processes are CPU and I/O intensive when the I/O issues occur?  Have you analyzed your queries?  Do you have the right indexes on the tables?  Are stats out-of-date?  Etc., etc.

Comment: Issues are high latency times, as measured by avg disk sec read on log and data drives. Reading are around .2 second. Side note: I know anti virus is one of a 1000 things which can cause this. What I am interested in is an efficient way to measure the performance cost of the anti-virus as well as validate its configuration. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Windows has some of the best tools to attribute performance issues to a particular application/driver/codepath. Antivirus developers themselves use a tool called Windows Performance toolkit (XPerf) to isolate performance issues. Its a free tool from Microsoft but it has a steep learning curve. It will show you I/O graphs, CPU utilization Graphs and you can zoom in on peaks in the graphs and see what was executing (full stack trace) at that time. Nothing gets more detailed than XPerf.